# rails form does not work anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, put

This form to update a work item does not work anymore.

The form is generated in the erb file using a this command:

```
<%= form_for(@work_item, :url => admin_workitem_update_path) do |f| %>
```

The generated tag looks like this:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/workitem/define/14" class="edit_workitem" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_workitem_14" method="put">
</form>
```

The route looks like this:

```
admin_workitem_update PUT    /admin/workitem/define/:workitem_id(.:format)
```

Follow-up: using :method => :post in the form tag works.

Why does rails generate the put method attribute?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about some code that isn't working? There's no way Chrome could remove a feature from Rails. Rails adds a hidden field to the form and then processes it on the server side, completely independent of the browser.

Comment: @Beerlington: :)) of course chrome would not remove something from rails. you might want to read the question a few times before you write someting. Also what does the hidden field has to do anything?

Comment: I did read the question, but it wasn't really a question... The hidden field is used to tell the application what REST method to use. Since PUT is not supported by all browsers, it fakes it by including a hidden field and converts it on the server side. Rails does not rely on the browser to support anything but GET and POST so even if no browsers supported PUT or DELETE, it would still work.

Comment: Here's some more info from the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#how-do-forms-with-put-or-delete-methods-work I suggest you read it.

Comment: Hi Beerlington, sorry about the comment with reading the question - must have been a bit tired.

the funny thing is that the hidden field was never generated, but the form tag gets put as a method attribute.

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/workitem/define/14" class="edit_workitem" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_workitem_14" method="put">
</form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEVER use equal sign befor form. I have the same problem with Instant Rails implementation. The tutorial on rails documentation should be used without <&=

```
<%= form_for(@work_item, :url => admin_workitem_update_path) do |f| %>
```

use insteand:

```
<% form_for(@work_item, :url => admin_workitem_update_path) do |f| %>
```

this is all

Comment: is correct and it should work, let us know if it is working or not